# Table cell break line when put the table in scrollable DIV?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got a problem. I create a table and put it in a DIV like this:

```
<div class="divScroll">
<table class="k-tbTemplate">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header </th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <a href="#null" style="float:left; ">asfasfa</a>
                <a href="#null" onclick="AddSA(this);" style="float:right; ">
                    <img src="add.PNG" alt="Add Shop"/></a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div style="float:left;">aaa</div>
                <div style="float:right;display:inline;">
                    <a href="#null">
                        <img alt="Add Shop" src="/add.PNG"/></a>
                    <a href="#null">
                        <img alt="Remove Shop" src="/rem.PNG"/></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Although `<td>` was set `white-space:nowrap`, it was still break line. If I don't put the table in a scrollable div, it works good.

[Full html code and css style is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/JHHQW/1/)

Anybody help me on this issue.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It doesn't appear to be breaking the line for me in Chrome

Comment: I just updated demo link, I run in Firefox 9 and IE 8.

Comment: You're floating elements, `white-space` won't apply to block level elements. Try using `display: inline` or `inline-block` instead of floats, or set min-widths on the TDs / table.

Comment: div width is the issue here check out this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/JHHQW/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/JHHQW/3/)

Comment: In fact, the table is longer than container div, so it always overflow. I can not set width of div to different value.

Comment: if you need an overflow table adjust the div size

Comment: this issue doesn't happen in Chrome, only in FF and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is not the cause. It’s the setting of a fixed width (300px) on the `div` element containing the table. The cells are squeezed, and the effect of floating causes what you might regard as line breaking. If you want the contents of a cell on one line, just put it one line, without using elements that cause line breaks, like `div`.